# Entity framework fill in virtual property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF 6 with code first, repository pattern + UOW pattern.

I have ca method that will return all items of a specific entity.

Ex: `UnitOfWork.Customers.GetAllCustomers()` that will return an IQueryable

In the Customer model I have a virtual property called `Adress` that will be filled in at runtime

`public virtual Address Address { get; set; }`

Whenever in my controller I call the GetAllCustomers, all information are there except the Address property that is null.

Any ideas how to return also the address ?

Comment: Are your relationships setup correctly?

Comment: If LazyLoading is turned off, you need to explicitely include the Address in GetAllCustomers : customers.Include(c => c.Address) ...

Answer (score 6):

See [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

Either eager-load using `.Include(c => c.Address)` or enable lazy loading so EF will do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The Lazy Loading, load the entity only if Its accessed for the first time. You should load it manually:

```
.Include(c => c.Address)
```

OR

```
.Include("Address")
```